# Perl: How do you sort and convert, items of an array by number of appearances

Tags: arrays, perl

first post here (and program that i'm trying to make for that matter!).

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but what i want to do is sort my array by how many times the items inside them appear and then translate the amount of times they appear into numbers.

From this:

```
@array = (blue, red, blue, green, red, blue)
```

I want to create this:

```
@array1 = (blue, blue, blue, red, red, green)
```

and then from that i want to create this:

```
@array2 = (3, 2, 1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: count the number of occurences with a hash, ``map {$hash{$_}++} @array`` then use the hash in the ``sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } @array``

Comment: I have tried using the sort function, and that does bunch them together, but in alphabetic order rather than number of appearances.

Comment: What is it that you're ultimately looking to achieve?  Do you need that intermediate array?  There may be better ways to get your desired solution, like using a hash as Vorsprung suggested.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to create a word counter (listing the word and the amount of times it has been used). And i do know that there is a better way to do this. But with my limited knowledge (started learning perl yesterday) creating 2 arrays and then combining them into a hash for presentation is the best i can come up with.

Comment: @JackPettersson: Have you tried reading the documentation for the sort() function? Or the Perl FAQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @array = qw(blue red blue green red blue);

my %seen;
$seen{$_}++ for @array;

my @array1 = sort { $seen{$b} <=> $seen{$a} } @array;
my @array2 = sort { $b <=> $a } values %seen;
```

`%seen` is hash which holds frequency/count for each color:

```
   blue  => 3,
   red   => 2,
   green => 1,
```

First sort uses hash as count look up in order to sort colors in descending order regarding number of corresponding  occurrences. Second sort is plain numerical descending sort for hash values (`1,2,3`).

Comment: It would be worth explaining for the next person who has this problem